# How do I batch-copy ID3v1 info to ID3v2 and back? in MP3 music files

Tags: mp3, id3

I want to batch copy the info in one ID3v1 field, to it's counterpart on the ID3v2 side including both lyrics fields so that all media players pick up the same data, including the ones that don't have support for ID3v2.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

MPTagThat program allow you to batch search lyrics in internet and add tag with it into audio file

here it is: http://www.team-mediaportal.com/extensions/music/mptagthat

Check [Best free MP3 tag editor](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-mp3-tag-editor.htm) page too

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ChrisF edited answer, is it ok now?